# Dativ und/oder "für"

Tags: grammar, dative

Manchmal kann man wahlweise den Dativ oder "für" benutzen:

- Das Buch ist mir zu kompliziert. Das Buch ist zu kompliziert für mich.
- Meine Frau hat mir Essen gekocht. Meine Frau hat Essen für mich gekocht.

Manchmal geht nur "für":

- Das war eine großartige Erfahrung für mich.
- Hast du ein Geschenk für mich?

Gibt es eine allgemeine Regel, die zwischen beiden Möglichkeiten unterscheidet?

Comment: "Das Buch ist schwer für mich" -> Würd ich nie so sagen. Wenn, dann "zu schwer" und dann gehen beide Formen. "Das Buch ist mir zu schwer". Dass das zweite Beispiel nicht mit "mir" geht, denke ich liegt am Verb "haben". Damit hast du auch schon im Grunde deine Regel. Es hängt vom Verb ab. "jdm haben" ist falsch, "jdm kochen", "jdm zu schwer/kompliziert sein" sind richtig.

Comment: @Em1: Alternative: Das war eine großartige Erfahrung für mich. Aber: Es ist mir ein Greuel. Natürlich kann man eine Liste aller Verben mit den jeweils möglichen Varianten machen, aber das ist dasselbe wie "es gibt keine Regel". Und da die Ergänzung in allen Fällen nicht teil des eigentlich Verbmusters ist, denke ich, dass es eigentlich eine geben müsste.

Answer (score 5):

**Versucht kurz:** Ein Dativ kann im Allgemeinen mit einer Für-Konstruktion ersetzt werden, wenn der Satz ohne ihn immer noch grammatikalisch und semantisch korrekt, aber nicht mehr bedeutungsgleich ist.

Sprichwörter bzw. Redewendungen stellen mögliche Ausnahmen dar.

---

**Das Buch ist mir zu kompliziert.**

Hier kann *mir* zwar mit *für mich* ausgetauscht werden, ändert genaugenommen aber auch die Bedeutung. Statt *zu* kann auch ein anderes Gradpartikel (allzu, sehr, enorm, genug etc.) vorkommen. Der Unterschied liegt darin, von wem die Einschätzung ausgeht/ausging. Anhand zweier Beispiele:

1. für jemanden

   > A und B wollen ein Buch für den Deutschlerner C aussuchen. B schlägt Goethes "Faust" vor.
   >
   > A meint: "Das ist sicher zu schwer für ihn."

   Die Einschätzung geht von A aus, deshalb *für ihn*.
2. jemandem

   > A und B wollen ein Buch für den Deutschlerner C aussuchen. B schlägt Goethes "Faust" 
   >   vor.
   >
   > A trägt das Buch zu C, welcher meint: "Das ist mir zu schwer."
   >   A kehrt zu B zurück und richtet aus: "Es ist ihm zu schwer."

   Die Einschätzung ging von C aus, deshalb *ihm*.

Dieser Dativ heißt *dativus iudicantis*; ein Gradpartikel (*zu* etc.) ist m. M. n. unerlässlich.
Obwohl C genauso gut "Das ist zu schwer für mich" sagen hätte können, scheint mir diese Variante immer noch eine externe Einschätzung der *Schwere* zu implizieren. C könnte z. B. ein Vorurteil über das Buch oder von jemand anderem etwas darüber gehört haben.

**Mein Mann hat mir etwas gekocht.**

Bei Verben,

- die transitiv verwendet werden
- zusätzlich zum Akkusativobjekt ein Dativobjekt erhalten
- generell aber kein Dativobjekt brauchen
- ausdrücken, dass etwas zu jemandes Vorteil geschieht,

macht es im Allgemeinen keinen Unterschied, welche Konstruktion man nimmt:

> kochen
>
> - Mein Mann kocht etwas.
> - Mein Mann kocht mir etwas.
> - 
> - Vorteil des Bekochtwerdens
>
> Mein Mann kocht etwas für mich.

**Hast du ein Geschenk für mich?**

Hier ist *für mich* an *ein Geschenk haben* gebunden und kann deshalb auch nicht ausgetauscht werden. Bei dem Satz "Ich habe ein Geschenk" fehlt entweder etwas oder es ist schon bzw. wird noch klar, für wen das Geschenk bestimmt ist.

---

<sub>(Aus den Kommentaren)</sub>

**Das war eine großartige Erfahrung für mich.**

Betrachtet man ähnliche Wendungen mit *Freude* oder *Ehre* (wo *für mich* sehr wohl mit *mir* ausgetauscht werden kann), erkennt man, dass es am Wort *Erfahrung* liegt (empfinden, kein Artikel/machen, Artikel). Ich kann den Unterschied aber nicht formalisieren.

**Es ist mir ein Gräuel.**

Hier scheint mir "Es ist für mich ein Gräuel" gleichwertig zu sein.